# LeakCanary FailAnnotatedTestOnLeakRunListener/@FailTestOnLeak not failing my instrumentation test

Tags: android, android-instrumentation, leakcanary

Following the guide [here](https://square.github.io/leakcanary/recipes/#running-leakcanary-in-instrumentation-tests), I've added [@FailTestOnLeak](https://github.com/square/leakcanary/blob/7edf572f4000391e28ef74c5f1ed62aa61ffd945/leakcanary-android-instrumentation/src/main/java/leakcanary/FailTestOnLeak.kt#L16) to my test and [FailAnnotatedTestOnLeakRunListener](https://github.com/square/leakcanary/blob/7edf572f4000391e28ef74c5f1ed62aa61ffd945/leakcanary-android-instrumentation/src/main/java/leakcanary/FailAnnotatedTestOnLeakRunListener.kt#L17) as a listener, everything seem to be working as expected with leaks being found and I've traced FailTestOnLeakRunListener to properly executing its [failTest()](https://github.com/square/leakcanary/blob/7edf572f4000391e28ef74c5f1ed62aa61ffd945/leakcanary-android-instrumentation/src/main/java/leakcanary/FailTestOnLeakRunListener.kt#L171) routine but my problem is that the test does not fail (but passes). Digging a little deeper, looks like the underlying code that actually tries to trigger the test failure is via instrumentation.sendStatus(-2, ...) ([here](https://github.com/square/leakcanary/blob/1d93c749db8991f99af9cd5bec7aeb8702a9f053/leakcanary-android-instrumentation/src/main/java/leakcanary/internal/InstrumentationTestResultPublisher.kt#L28)). I've confirmed this code executes but yet my test continues to pass. Any idea why my test might not be failing properly?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.